# How to resolve a boolean promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using npm package isAdmin to check if the my node process had admin rights or not, this returns a boolean promise.

**File.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="../libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script
</head>
<body onload="mainFunc()" style="background: white;">


</body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
const isAdmin = require('is-admin');

let bAdminPrivilege = false;

async function mainFunc() {
    alert(bAdminPrivilege);//false
    bAdminPrivilege = await checkAdmin();
    alert(bAdminPrivilege); //[object promise]
}

async function checkAdmin () {
    bAdminPrivilege = await isAdmin(); 
    alert(bAdminPrivilege);
    return  bAdminPrivilege;     
}
```

I use async/await to resolve this promise, for checkAdmin I see different values true is expected one, but in function main I see [promise boolean] , this is what I am puzzled about, am I resolving the promise correctly?

Comment: You're not awaiting for the `checkAdmin()` function, which is, in itself, an `async` function.

Comment: I have edited the question I made mainFunc to be async and checkAdmin() await , now both the alerts in side main are false, where I expected second alert to be true !

Comment: You can eliminate the second function (`checkAdmin`) altogether, it's just clutter with no purpose, just set the `mainFunc` to be `async` (as you did) and do `bAdminPrivilege = await isAdmin(); alert(bAdminPrivilege)`. Your 2nd function is convoluted and is always returning the default bAdminPrivilege(false) because it's not awaiting the resolution of the async fn in it. You could add `await (async () => ...` in your checkAdmin, it will then work but it's still useless.

Comment: Thanks  Milan Velebit,I want this to be in separate function so I can use it in many place.

Comment: @karansys Did you read the answers to the question linked above? `await` doesn't actually _do_ anything to the promise. It is a mechanism for getting the function to pause and wait for the promise before moving on to the next line of code inside that function. This just creates an all new promise that must be awaited in its own right. As Milan said, your `checkAdmin` function doesn't do anything useful. It's nothing more than an extremely roundabout way of calling `isAdmin()`.

Comment: Thanks  JLRishe , I have much clear idea now

Comment: With this knowledge I created demo , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043642/promise-is-not-resolved-using-async-await