# Promise is not resolved using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to learn async/ await of promise I have created demo code

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
              async function getTested() {
              alert("line");
              let pp = await test1();
              alert(pp); //expected to print hello

              }

            async function test1 () {
                alert("line 9");
                let promise = await test2();
                alert(promise); //expected to print hello
                return promise;
            }

            function test2 () {
                alert("line 15");
                let promise = new Promise.resolve('hello');
                alert(promise);
                return promise;  
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="getTested()"></body>
</html>
```

Here I used async/await to resolve the promise I excepted it to print 'hello' in test1 and getTested. What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: `new Promise.resolve` `<-` something wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Promise.resolve` `<-` something wrong there.

Initialize and return the Promise object.

```
let promise = new Promise(function(r) {
    r("hello");
});
```

Or, you can follow an approach similar as you wanted to follow:

```
Promise.resolve("hello");
```

```js
async function getTested() {
  let pp = await test1();
  console.log(pp); //expected to print hello

}

async function test1() {
  let promise = await test2();
  console.log(promise); //expected to print hello
  return promise;
}

function test2() {
  return Promise.resolve("hello");
}

getTested()
```

Comment: @MichaelDorst Most likely because this is a case of _"read the docs and the problem would not be a problem"_. Imho this should have been closed as typo...

Comment: @Andreas for sure, the _question_ may deserve a downvote, but why downvote the answers when they are correct?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question or the answers.

Comment: @MichaelDorst The same reason. Instead of answering this question for the sweet karma this should have been closed. Now with the "answers" it is not eligible for the [auto-delete/roomba](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why/296609#296609)

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good reason for a downvote to me. I suggest that people who think this question deserves to be closed should simply cast a close vote.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Promise.resolve(value)

change your test3 function to

```
function test2 () {
  alert("line 15");
  let promise = Promise.resolve('hello');
  alert(promise);
  return promise;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when you don't put `new` before `Promise.resolve('hello')`.

I've added some strings to your strings so we can see which function is outputting each string. This helps you see the order things happened more clearly.

I'm using `console.log` instead of `alert()`, so that you can see everything at once by running the code snippet below:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
              async function getTested() {
              console.log("getTested: line1");
              let pp = await test1();
              console.log(`getTested pp: ${pp}`); //expected to print hello
              }

            async function test1 () {
                console.log(`test1: line 9`);
                let promise = await test2();
                console.log(`test1: ${promise}`); //expected to print hello
                return promise;
            }

            async function test2 () {
                console.log("test2: line 15");
                let promise = Promise.resolve('hello');
                console.log(`test2: ${await promise}`);
                return promise;  
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="getTested()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are these answers being downvoted? Are they wrong? Can someone leave a comment to explain why they are wrong?

Comment: @MichaelDorst I up-voted the question, myself, and I didn't down-vote anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "new" in front of the Promise.

Do:

```
let promise = Promise.resolve('hello');
```

Instead of:

```
let promise = new Promise.resolve('hello');
```